# Fan speed goes up when opening GNOME Image Viewer

Tags: 11.10, dell, fan, eog

Maybe someone can help me to control the fan speed of my Dell Vostro 3450 with Ubuntu 11.10 X64 installed. When I open GNOME Image Viewer my fan speed is going up and spinning very fast.

I would like to know the reason why it does this.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is pegged and it's heating up when you open Gnome Image Viewer. The fan speed is automatically adjusted by your BIOS via [AMD Cool'n'Quiet™](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/cool-n-quiet/Pages/cool-n-quiet.aspx) or some other similar motherboard feature. Open the System Monitor to see how much CPU the app is using. EOG doesn't work for me in 11.10 because of a few bugs and I've since moved to Mirage.

Comment: My CPU Intel Core i5. Then using Gnome Image Viewer my system monitor show 44% CPU load.

Comment: 44% would be enough to get your CPU to the next frequency step so it's not pegged but it should be enough to get the fan going. Does the fan run faster if you run `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1024k`?

Comment: Yes fan run faster then insert "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1024k" commmand in terminal.

Comment: That dd command simply pegs your CPU and it showed how your fan reacts when the CPU is busy and the temperature rises.

Comment: so no solution for that problem? maybe EOG update can help?

Comment: Your question was answered. You asked why your fan spins faster when you run EOG. I also provided a solution, to install Mirage. http://mirageiv.berlios.de/

Comment: @dzukauskas, it isn't a problem.  It is perfectly normal for the fan to speed up when the system is under load.